# Injection in the setUp() method causes the framework not to wait for the Future to complete

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

I am testing an AngularDart component. I am trying to fetch the template and put it in `TemplateCache` in the `setUp()` method. For this I need to inject the template cache. However the inject in the `setUp()` makes the framework continue to the test method and not waiting for the `Future` to complete. Here is a simplified example.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:mock/mock.dart';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:angular/mock/test_injection.dart';
import 'package:angular/mock/module.dart';
import 'package:di/di.dart';


class MyTest {

  static main() {

    group("SetUp with future that waits", () {
      setUp(() {
        return new Future.value("First").then((_) => print(_));
      });

      test("Welcome to the world of tomorrow!", () {
        print("Second");
      });
    });

    group("SetUp with future that doesn't wait", () {
      setUp(inject((Injector inject) { // injection causes the test to not wait
        return new Future.value("First").then((_) => print(_));
      }));

      test("Welcome to the world of tomorrow!", () {
        print("Second");
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In the console you can see the printed messages: First, Second, Second, First.

I think it must be that the `inject` is not returning the `Future`. What else can I do to both have the framework injecting objects that I need and waiting for the `Future` in the `setUp()`?

Comment: What `inject` method are you calling? Can you please add your imports?

Comment: I'll get to the code only tomorrow, I am almost sure it is this library: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/mock/test_injection.dart

Comment: Please make a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I needed. The mistake was trying to return something from the `inject` itself. It is actually as simple as this:

```dart
  setUp(() {
    // ...
    inject((Injectable injectable) {
        // inject the objects here and save them in variables
    });
    // work with the variables
    return new Future.value("First").then((_) => print(_));
  });
```